# Using Enterprise Libraray SqlConfigurationSource

Tags: .net, database, configuration, enterprise-library

I want to move all of my enterprise libraray configuration information, as well as some application configuration information into a database.

I am having trouble understanding how to create the ConfigurationDb object. Where can I find information and/or tutorials on moving your application & enterprise library configuration into a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the [latest](http://entlib.codeplex.com/releases/view/56812) implementation of the SqlConfigurationSource for Enterprise Library 5.0. It contains necessary sql scripts and short deployment instructions.

Comment: i did but it didn't help that much.. need to know how configDB will be implemented and not with mock

Comment: I don't understand. The SqlConfigurationSource download includes complete code for storing Entlib config in MS Sql Server, including change monitoring. What are you looking for?

Comment: Found it, i missed a file. my bad